# Type in Secret Message get Forwarded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get forwarded to a page called 'test.html' by typing in the sentence 'hello' on the page. For example, when I type in 'hello' on the page, I would get forwarded to test.html . It wouldn't be in a text box; I would type it without seeing what I'm typing. I've researched this online but can't find anything on this topic.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: You want to *capture keystrokes*. Have you researched in that direction?

Comment: Very easy to create. Very easy to detect. Very insecure.

Comment: If you need a password, you'd be much better off with SSL and a password field on a form like everyone else does. Users have come to expect a login to perform a certain way. Don't make more work for yourself than you have to by trying to reinvent a convention - it's most likely not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what purpose it will serve but You can do something like that.

- Add `keypress` listener on document.
- Maintain one variable for holding the typed text say `sec`.
- in your key press listener,
  Concatenate the pressed key with the `sec` and compare  `if
  sec=="hello" do redirect`

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OmAfUYA/2/)

Javascript

```
(function(){
document.addEventListener("keypress",fun);
var sec='';
function fun(e){
sec += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
if(sec=="hello"){
alert("Hello typed!");  //replace this with  redirect
sec='';
}    
}

})();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! I can't believe I forgot about keypress :P I'm pretty new to JavaScript.

Comment: so now you can accept this answer. :)

Comment: What does the 'sec' do?

Comment: nothing special. Just a temp variable to hold the value that is typed.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Is codewithlogic your website?

Comment: yes! Please don't make the discussion long. Chat is much suited for that discussion. :)

Comment: Are you sure You are talking to Him?